# Add -webkit -moz -ms -o css rules via JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css

Ok, I understand JavaScript addRule with simple css rules:

```
firstRule.style.color = "red";
```

But how do I add for example this:

```
-webkit-transform:translateX(16em) perspective(600px) rotateY(10deg)";
```

Something like this?:

```
firstRule.style.-webkit-transform = "translateX(16em) perspective(600px) rotateY(10deg)";
```

Because it does not work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

camelize it (replace any dash with uppercase  character that comes after the dash):

```
firstRule.style.WebkitTransform = "translateX(16em) perspective(600px) rotateY(10deg)";
```

You can also use `.setProperty`:

```
firstRule.style.setProperty( "-webkit-transform", "translateX(16em) perspective(600px) rotateY(10deg)" );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```
firstRule.style["-webkit-transform"] = firstRule.style["-moz-transform"] = "translateX(16em) perspective(600px) rotateY(10deg)";
```

Just an example to adding the '-moz' prefix as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('firstRule').setAttribute('style','xxxxxx');
```

clean and simple

Comment: This overwrites all other styles, it's not so simple when you need to retain them by concating strings

Comment: just get the actual style and set it with document.getElementById('firstRule').setAttribute('style', variable+'xxxxxx'); not that hard if you think a little

Comment: I never said string concating is hard :P just annoying